# CROSS APPLY makes SSRS report very slow

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a slow report and have isolated the problem to a dataset that contains a CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT VALS = LTRIM(stuff( 
          ( 
          select distinct ', ' + ltrim(rtrim(VAL)) 
            FROM 
            SELECT t1.ID,t2.VAL FROM dbo.t1  t1
                CROSS APPLY dbo.(ID) t2
        for XML PATH('')                        
        ),1,1,''))
```

This query takes only 15 seconds in SQL normally, but when running from SSRS it takes 15 minutes. Why?

EDIT:

Changed to use a @TEMP table to insert the values into at the start, then query it in a select and we are back to normal processing time.

Comment: most likely param sniffing

Comment: Excellent article here:   http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html